# Transformar varias listas en un diccionario Python

Tags: python

Buen día gente, tengo 4 listas donde guardo mas de mil registros, en este caso solo 7 para efectos prueba y error. De esas 4 listas quiero armar un diccionario en donde la clave sea la marca y que dentro de esta agrupe los productos que dicha marca(una marca puede tener muchos productos), utilize el update pensando si que no encuentra el elemento lo agrega, pero no funciona; luego será subida a MONGODB. podrían orientarme, gracias de antemano.

**Codigo de Python**

```
lsCleanProduct = ['Arroz', 'Azucar','fideo','aceite','chocolate','Saco arroz','galon aceite']
lsCleanMark = ['costeño','BlancaFlor','MAXIMA','primor','nestle','costeño', 'primor']
price = ['1.5','10','14','5.8','2','4.8','4.1']
imagen=['img1','img2','img3','img4','img5','img6','img7']

data = {}
i=0

for indice in range(len((lsCleanProduct))):
        i+=1
        
        if lsCleanMark[indice] not in data:
                data[lsCleanMark[indice]]= {
                    '_id' : i,
                    'Nombre' : lsCleanProduct[indice],
                    'Marca' : lsCleanMark[indice],
                    'Supermercado' : 'Metro'
                }
        else:
                data[lsCleanMark[indice]].update({
                        '_id': i,
                        'Nombre': lsCleanProduct[indice],
                        'Marca': lsCleanMark[indice],
                        'Supermercado': 'Metro'
                })

print(data)
```

Comment: Puede proporcionar la salida que desea?

Comment: {
    "costeño" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "Nombre" : "Arroz",
            "Marca" : "costeño",
            "Supermercado" : "Metro"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Buen día @MatteoBosio, escribiste el comentario casi al mismo tiempo que estaba redactando una respuesta, el "_id" es necesario? Porque podrías simplemente utilizar el índice de la lista por marca. De igual forma creo que si necesitaras el "_id" puedes agregarlo adaptando la respuesta que puse. Por otra parte, las aclaraciones van como edición a la pregunta y no como comentarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes hacerlo al combinar [`zip`](https://interactivechaos.com/es/python/function/zip#:%7E:text=La%20funci%C3%B3n%20zip%20devuelve%20un,elementos%20del%20iterador%20m%C3%A1s%20corto.) con [`setdefault`](https://python-para-impacientes.blogspot.com/2015/04/defaultdict-vs-setdefault.html).

Ejemplo completo:

```
lsCleanProduct = ['Arroz', 'Azucar','fideo','aceite','chocolate','Saco arroz','galon aceite']
lsCleanMark = ['costeño','BlancaFlor','MAXIMA','primor','nestle','costeño', 'primor']
price = ['1.5','10','14','5.8','2','4.8','4.1']
imagen=['img1','img2','img3','img4','img5','img6','img7']

# Creamos un diccionario vacío
d = {}

# Creamos un iterador de tuplas e iteramos en sus elementos
for producto, marca, precio, img in zip(lsCleanProduct, lsCleanMark, price, imagen):
    # Utilizamos setdefault para crear una nueva llave en caso de que no exista con una lista vacía
    # Y adjuntamos un nuevo diccionario con append
    # En caso de que la llave exista no se crea una nueva, solo se adjunta el nuevo elemento
    d.setdefault(marca, []).append({'Producto': producto, 'Precio': precio, 'Imagen': img})
    
print(d)
```

Esto devuelve el siguiente diccionario:

```
{'costeño': [
    {'Producto': 'Arroz', 'Precio': '1.5', 'Imagen': 'img1'},
    {'Producto': 'Saco arroz', 'Precio': '4.8', 'Imagen': 'img6'}
 ],
 'BlancaFlor': [
    {'Producto': 'Azucar', 'Precio': '10', 'Imagen': 'img2'}
 ],
 'MAXIMA': [
    {'Producto': 'fideo', 'Precio': '14', 'Imagen': 'img3'}
 ],
 'primor': [
    {'Producto': 'aceite', 'Precio': '5.8', 'Imagen': 'img4'},
    {'Producto': 'galon aceite', 'Precio': '4.1', 'Imagen': 'img7'}
 ],
 'nestle': [
    {'Producto': 'chocolate', 'Precio': '2', 'Imagen': 'img5'}
 ]
}
```

Si quisieras acceder a sus elementos puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
print(d['costeño'][1])
```

De esa forma accedes al elemento con índice 1 de la llave "costeño" y el resultado es:

```
{'Producto': 'Saco arroz', 'Precio': '4.8', 'Imagen': 'img6'}
```